# Community Builder Modal slide-in action

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Does anyone have experience getting a modal pop-up on a Salesforce community page to slide in from one side rather than popping up? Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad, normally, we woudl expect you to provide what you have tried in your post and add a specific problem you are facing. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take te [tour] in prder to get familair with the site. thankks